# Missing option to lock screen after last Remote Desktop session disconnects

Tags: 11.10, remote-desktop, lock-screen

After installing 11.10 I noticed that the blanking the monitor froze my system (it was not trying to sleep)  When I turned that off the the screen did not lock; also there was no option to lock the session when the last VNC session disconnected.  I removed the `gnome-screensaver` package and installed `xscreensaver`.  Now it locks just fine on the timeout, but I still need it to lock after the last VNC session disconnects.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to enable it (press alt+f2 and type it on the box or run it on a terminal)

`gsettings set org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect true`

To disable it

`gsettings set org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false`

Comment: Bruno, thanks for the response.  I set this key, and even checked it with gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.vino
It did not work